# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'CUSTOMER' does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, computer-science, derby

I have a prog that takes input from jframe and tries to store that data into a derby embedded database. I have tried to run a simple insert statement to test the database and it gives me the "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'CUSTOMER' does not exist." Error. What am I doing wrong?`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Label;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

public class Auto extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5777093322764526515L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField f_name;
    private JTextField l_name;
    private JTextField f_name2;
    private JTextField l_name2;
    private JTextField Age;
    private JTextField issuing;
    private JTextField liscense_num;
    private JTextField rental;
    private JTextField return_d;
    private JTextField total;
    private JTextField Age2;
    private JTextField issuing2;
    private JTextField liscense_num2;
    private JTextField rental2;
    private JTextField return_d2;
    private JTextField total2;
    private JTextField agreement_id;
    private Button Submit_button;
    private Button Clear_button;
    private JButton load_button;
    private Button Update_button;
    private Button return_car;
    private JComboBox<?> car_select, car_select2;
    private JRadioButton cc_button;
    private JRadioButton cc_button2;
    private JRadioButton debit_button;
    private JRadioButton debit_button2;
    private static String url;
    private static Connection myConnection;
    private static Statement myStatement;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
                    url = "jdbc:derby:MyDB;create=true";
                    myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    myStatement = myConnection.createStatement( );
                    Auto frame = new Auto();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Auto() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 694, 497);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTabbedPane Auto_Pane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        Auto_Pane.setBounds(5, 5, 422, 432);
        contentPane.add(Auto_Pane);

        JPanel New_rent = new JPanel();
        Auto_Pane.addTab("New Rental", null, New_rent, null);
        New_rent.setLayout(null);

        JLabel first_name = new JLabel("First Name: ");
        first_name.setBounds(12, 8, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(first_name);

        f_name = new JTextField(15);
        f_name.setBounds(97, 5, 116, 22);
        New_rent.add(f_name);
        f_name.setColumns(10);

        l_name = new JTextField(15);
        l_name.setBounds(97, 40, 116, 22);
        l_name.setColumns(10);
        New_rent.add(l_name);

        JLabel last_name = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
        last_name.setBounds(12, 43, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(last_name);

        JLabel age = new JLabel("Age: ");
        age.setBounds(12, 76, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(age);

        Age = new JTextField(2);
        Age.setBounds(97, 75, 35, 22);
        Age.setColumns(10);
        New_rent.add(Age);

        JLabel liscense = new JLabel("License #: ");
        liscense.setBounds(12, 113, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(liscense);


        JLabel issuing_st = new JLabel("Issuing State: ");
        issuing_st.setBounds(12, 146, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(issuing_st);

        issuing = new JTextField(2);
        issuing.setBounds(97, 143, 116, 22);
        issuing.setColumns(10);
        New_rent.add(issuing);

        liscense_num = new JTextField(13);
        liscense_num.setBounds(97, 110, 116, 22);
        liscense_num.setColumns(10);
        New_rent.add(liscense_num);

        String[] carStrings = { "Compact", "Midsized", "Standard", "Full Size", "SUV", "Mini Van" };
        car_select = new JComboBox<Object>(carStrings);
        car_select.setBounds(97, 178, 112, 22);
        New_rent.add(car_select);

        JLabel car_type = new JLabel("Car Type:");
        car_type.setBounds(12, 181, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(car_type);

        JLabel rent_date = new JLabel("Rental Date:");
        rent_date.setBounds(12, 216, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(rent_date);

        rental = new JTextField(10);
        rental.setBounds(97, 213, 116, 22);
        rental.setColumns(10);
        New_rent.add(rental);

        JLabel return_date = new JLabel("Return Date:");
        return_date.setBounds(12, 251, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(return_date);

        return_d = new JTextField(10);
        return_d.setBounds(97, 248, 116, 22);
        return_d.setColumns(10);
        New_rent.add(return_d);

        JLabel total_num = new JLabel("Total:");
        total_num.setBounds(12, 283, 84, 16);
        New_rent.add(total_num);

        total = new JTextField(7);
        total.setBounds(97, 280, 116, 22);
        total.setColumns(10);
        New_rent.add(total);

        JLabel payment_type = new JLabel("Payment Type:");
        payment_type.setBounds(12, 317, 100, 16);
        New_rent.add(payment_type);

        cc_button = new JRadioButton("Credit Card");
        cc_button.setBounds(128, 313, 127, 25);
        New_rent.add(cc_button);

        debit_button = new JRadioButton("Debit");
        debit_button.setBounds(259, 313, 127, 25);
        New_rent.add(debit_button);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(debit_button);
        group.add(cc_button);

        Submit_button = new Button("Submit");
        Submit_button.setBounds(12, 356, 99, 24);
        Submit_button.addActionListener(this);
        New_rent.add(Submit_button);

        Clear_button = new Button("Clear Form");
        Clear_button.setBounds(128, 356, 99, 24);
        Clear_button.addActionListener(this);
        New_rent.add(Clear_button);

        JPanel Current_rent = new JPanel();
        Auto_Pane.addTab("Current Rental", null, Current_rent, null);
        Current_rent.setLayout(null);

        load_button = new JButton("Load Current Rental Agreements");
        load_button.addActionListener(this);
        load_button.setBounds(12, 13, 393, 25);
        Current_rent.add(load_button);

        List load_list = new List();
        load_list.setBounds(12, 54, 393, 229);
        Current_rent.add(load_list);

        JPanel Rental_ret = new JPanel();
        Auto_Pane.addTab("Rental Details", null, Rental_ret, null);
        Rental_ret.setLayout(null);

        JLabel first_name2 = new JLabel("First Name: ");
        first_name2.setBounds(15, 48, 71, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(first_name2);

        f_name2 = new JTextField(15);
        f_name2.setBounds(109, 45, 116, 22);
        Rental_ret.add(f_name2);
        f_name2.setColumns(10);

        l_name2 = new JTextField(15);
        l_name2.setBounds(109, 74, 116, 22);
        l_name2.setColumns(10);
        Rental_ret.add(l_name2);

        JLabel last_name2 = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
        last_name2.setBounds(15, 77, 69, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(last_name2);

        Age2 = new JTextField(2);
        Age2.setBounds(109, 109, 116, 22);
        Age2.setColumns(10);
        Rental_ret.add(Age2);

        JLabel liscense2 = new JLabel("License #: ");
        liscense2.setBounds(15, 141, 64, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(liscense2);


        JLabel issuing_st2 = new JLabel("Issuing State: ");
        issuing_st2.setBounds(15, 170, 83, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(issuing_st2);

        issuing2 = new JTextField(2);
        issuing2.setBounds(109, 167, 116, 22);
        issuing2.setColumns(10);
        Rental_ret.add(issuing2);

        liscense_num2 = new JTextField(13);
        liscense_num2.setBounds(109, 138, 116, 22);
        liscense_num2.setColumns(10);
        Rental_ret.add(liscense_num2);


        car_select2 = new JComboBox<Object>(carStrings);
        car_select2.setBounds(109, 197, 116, 22);
        Rental_ret.add(car_select2);

        JLabel car_type2 = new JLabel("Car Type:");
        car_type2.setBounds(15, 199, 57, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(car_type2);

        JLabel rent_date2 = new JLabel("Rental Date:");
        rent_date2.setBounds(15, 234, 71, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(rent_date2);

        JTextField rental2 = new JTextField(10);
        rental2.setBounds(109, 231, 116, 22);
        rental2.setColumns(10);
        Rental_ret.add(rental2);

        JLabel return_date2 = new JLabel("Return Date:");
        return_date2.setBounds(15, 269, 73, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(return_date2);

        JTextField return_d2 = new JTextField(10);
        return_d2.setColumns(10);
        return_d2.setBounds(109, 266, 116, 22);
        Rental_ret.add(return_d2);

        JLabel total_num2 = new JLabel("Total:");
        total_num2.setBounds(15, 298, 34, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(total_num2);

        JTextField total2 = new JTextField(7);
        total2.setColumns(10);
        total2.setBounds(109, 295, 116, 22);
        Rental_ret.add(total2);

        JLabel payment_type2 = new JLabel("Payment Type:");
        payment_type2.setBounds(15, 332, 86, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(payment_type2);

        cc_button2 = new JRadioButton("Credit Card");
        cc_button2.setBounds(109, 328, 93, 25);
        Rental_ret.add(cc_button2);

        debit_button2 = new JRadioButton("Debit");
        debit_button2.setBounds(220, 326, 57, 25);
        Rental_ret.add(debit_button2);

        ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
        group2.add(debit_button);
        group2.add(cc_button);

        JLabel age2 = new JLabel("Age: ");
        age2.setBounds(15, 112, 31, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(age2);

        Update_button = new Button("Update");
        Update_button.setBounds(15, 368, 83, 24);
        Rental_ret.add(Update_button);
        Update_button.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel Agreement = new JLabel("Agreement ID: ");
        Agreement.setBounds(15, 13, 93, 16);
        Rental_ret.add(Agreement);

        agreement_id = new JTextField();
        agreement_id.setColumns(10);
        agreement_id.setBounds(109, 10, 116, 22);
        Rental_ret.add(agreement_id);

        return_car = new Button("Return Car");
        return_car.setBounds(109, 368, 83, 24);
        Rental_ret.add(return_car);
        return_car.addActionListener(this);
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {

              if(action.getSource() == Submit_button){
                  try {
                      myStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Customer (FNAME, LNAME, AGE, LICNUM, STATE, CAR_TYPE, RENTDATE, RETURNDATE, TOTAL, PAYTYPE, RETURNED) VALUES('chen','lee', 40,'S633-433-83-400-0', 'FL', 'C', '2016-04-07', '2016-04-10', 213.47, 'Credit', true)");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


              }
              if(action.getSource() == load_button);
              if(action.getSource() == Clear_button);
              if(action.getSource() == return_car);
              if(action.getSource() == Update_button);


    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't create the table in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `Customers` table on your database. Your code insert but don't create the table.

Is necessary to create the table by your code or directly in your DBMS.

Example:

```
try {
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc...", "user", "pass");
    String com = "CREATE TABLE Customers(col1 VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, coln VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);";
    PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement(com);
    st.execute();
    st.close();
    System.out.println("OK!");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where `c` is a `Connection`.

Comment: I had created the DB by physically using a separate file for query. Is it not seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

OK I have the Table created under APP. But My INSERT statement does not work, even though the format is correct and query for create table worked from program. The Submit button has action listener so that's not the problem. Why is this statement not working?

try {
            myStatement.execute("create table Customer (AgreementID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1000, INCREMENT BY 1),  "
                    + "FNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,  LNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, AGE INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + "LICNUM VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  STATE VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, "
                    + "CAR_TYPE VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, RENTDATE VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,  RETURNDATE VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,  TOTAL DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,  "
                    + "PAYTYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, RETURNED BOOLEAN, constraint customer_id_pk primary key (AgreementID))");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        myStatement.execute("create table Customer (AgreementID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1000, INCREMENT BY 1),  "
                + "FNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,  LNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, AGE INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + "LICNUM VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  STATE VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, "
                + "CAR_TYPE VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, RENTDATE VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,  RETURNDATE VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,  TOTAL DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,  "
                + "PAYTYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, RETURNED BOOLEAN, constraint customer_id_pk primary key (AgreementID))");
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```